# Where can we get/download LaTeX fonts?

Tags: fonts, miktex

Where can we get/download LaTeX fonts automatically? I am using MiKTeX and I am looking for `bbm8.pfb` fonts.

Comment: LaTeX default font (named Computer Modern) should be included in your Miktex installation. Any extra font you wish to use has to be loaded via `\usepackage{}`, and will then be installed automatically by Miktex if needed. Maybe you should be more specific about what you need?

Comment: @T.Verron: In this form as you wrote it, this isn’t true: There are fonts, where no package `xyz.sty` exists. They need to be loaded by the lower level font selection commands, cf. `fntguide.pdf`. Also in MiKTeX the automatic installation depends on the settings, but you’re right in the default.

Comment: This font belongs to `bbm`, and a `bbm.sty` exists (cf. my comment to T. Verron). For further proceeding see Apurba’s answer regarding the MiKTeX package Manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the package you can install if directly from MiKTeX package manager. To use that font you can use `\usepackage{}` to use it. If you want to download, you can get all the fonts from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts. You can find help about how to use it and install it from the same site. You can even check the [Latex Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) for more information about font. All the information like how to install it, how to use it, how it looks like are given the catalogue. You can surf the font catalogue to find out which font will suit for you.

Hope this will help.